# std::function in combination with thread c++11 fails debug assertion in vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, visual-studio-2015

I want to build a helper class that can accept an std::function created via std::bind) so that i can call this class repeaded from another thread:

short example:

```
void loopme() {
    std::cout << "yay";
}

main () {
   LoopThread loop = { std::bind(&loopme) };
   loop.start();
   //wait 1 second
   loop.stop();
   //be happy about output
}
```

However, when calling stop() my current implementation will raise the following error: [debug assertion Failed , see Image: i.stack.imgur.com/aR9hP.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR9hP.png).

Does anyone know why the error is thrown ?
I don't even use vectors in this example.
When i dont call loopme from within the thread but directly output to std::cout, no error is thrown.

Here the full implementation of my class:

```
class LoopThread {
public:
    LoopThread(std::function<void(LoopThread*, uint32_t)> function) : function_{ function }, thread_{ nullptr }, is_running_{ false }, counter_{ 0 } {};
    ~LoopThread();
    void start();
    void stop();
    bool isRunning() { return is_running_; };
private:
    std::function<void(LoopThread*, uint32_t)> function_;
    std::thread* thread_;
    bool is_running_;
    uint32_t counter_;
    void executeLoop();
};

LoopThread::~LoopThread() {
    if (isRunning()) {
        stop();
    }
}

void LoopThread::start() {
    if (is_running_) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Thread is already running");
    }
    if (thread_ != nullptr) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Thread is not stopped yet");
    }
    is_running_ = true;
    thread_ = new std::thread{ &LoopThread::executeLoop, this };
}

void LoopThread::stop() {
    if (!is_running_) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Thread is already stopped");
    }
    is_running_ = false;
    thread_->detach();
}

void LoopThread::executeLoop() {
    while (is_running_) {
        function_(this, counter_);
        ++counter_;
    }
    if (!is_running_) {
        std::cout << "end";
    }
    //delete thread_;
    //thread_ = nullptr;
}
```

I used the following Googletest code for testing (however a simple main method containing the code should work):

```
void testfunction(pft::LoopThread*, uint32_t i) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
}

TEST(pfFiles, TestLoop)
{
    pft::LoopThread loop{ std::bind(&testfunction, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2) };
    loop.start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));

    loop.stop();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2500));
    std::cout << "Why does this fail";

}
```

Comment: but there's no vector in quoted code, did you omit smth important or you are saying that you dont use vector explcitily?

Comment: I haven't used Google Test before, but I assume your TEST() definition there should contain some sort of ASSERT() declarations?

Comment: offtopic: `std::thread` is movable, you dont really need (and want) to store it by pointer and manually delete it

Comment: your usage of `is_running_` is dangerous too, there is high chance you will never break the loop

Comment: I don't use a vector, maybe the testsystem is using one, i will evaluate this.
GoogleTest doesn't need a ASSERT(), you can have those, but if you leave them out it will just return green if the function can be called without an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of `is_running_` is undefined behavior, because you write in one thread and read in another without a synchronization barrier.

Partly due to this, your `stop()` doesn't stop anything.  Even without this UB (ie, you "fix" it by using an atomic), it just tries to say "oy, stop at some point", by the end it does not even attempt to guarantee the stop happened.

Your code calls `new` needlessly.  There is no reason to use a `std::thread*` here.

Your code violates the rule of 5.  You wrote a destructor, then neglected copy/move operations.  It is ridiculously fragile.

As `stop()` does nothing of consequence to stop a thread, your thread with a pointer to `this` outlives your `LoopThread` object.  `LoopThread` goes out of scope, destroying what the pointer your `std::thread` stores.  The still running `executeLoop` invokes a `std::function` that has been destroyed, then increments a counter to invalid memory (possibly on the stack where another variable has been created).

Roughly, there is 1 fundamental error in using `std` threading in every 3-5 lines of your code (not counting interface declarations).

Beyond the technical errors, the design is wrong as well; using `detach` is almost always a horrible idea; unless you have a promise you make ready at thread exit and then wait on the completion of that promise somewhere, doing that and getting anything like a clean and dependable shutdown of your program is next to impossible.

As a guess, the vector error is because you are stomping all over stack memory and following nearly invalid pointers to find functions to execute.  The test system either puts an array index in the spot you are trashing and then the debug `vector` catches that it is out of bounds, or a function pointer that half-makes sense for your std function execution to run, or somesuch.

---

Only communicate through synchronized data between threads.  That means `atomic` data, or `mutex` guarded, unless you are getting ridiculously fancy.  You don't understand threading enough to get fancy.  You don't understand threading enough to copy someone who got fancy and properly use it.  Don't get fancy.

Don't use `new`.  Almost never, ever use `new`.  Use `make_shared` or `make_unique` if you absolutely have to.  But use those rarely.

Don't `detach` a thread.  Period.  Yes this means you might have to wait for it to finish a loop or somesuch.  Deal with it, or write a thread manager that does the waiting at shutdown or somesuch.

Be extremely clear about what data is owned by what thread.  Be extremely clear about when a thread is finished with data.  Avoid using data shared between threads; communicate by passing values (or pointers to immutable shared data), and get information from `std::future`s back.

---

There are a number of hurdles in learning how to program.  If you have gotten this far, you have passed a few.  But you probably know people who learned along side of you that fell over at one of the earlier hurdles.

- Sequence, that things happen one after another.
- Flow control.
- Subprocedures and functions.
- Looping.
- Recursion.
- Pointers/references and dynamic vs automatic allocation.
- Dynamic lifetime management.
- Objects and Dynamic dispatch.
- Complexity
- Coordinate spaces
- Message
- Threading and Concurrency
- Non-uniform address spaces, Serialization and Networking
- Functional programming, meta functions, currying, partial application, Monads

This list is not complete.

The point is, each of these hurdles can cause you to crash and fail as a programmer, and getting each of these hurdles right is hard.

**Threading is hard**.  Do it the easy way.  Dynamic lifetime management is hard.  Do it the easy way.  In both cases, extremely smart people have mastered the "manual" way to do it, and the result is programs that exhibit random unpredictable/undefined behavior and crash a lot.  Muddling through manual resource allocation and deallocation and multithreaded code can be made to work, but the result is usually someone whose small programs work accidentally (they work insofar as you fixed the bugs you noticed).  And when you master it, initial mastery comes in the form of holding an entire program's "state" in uour head and understanding how it works; this fails to scale to large many-developer code bases, so younusually graduate to having large programs that work accidentally.

Both `make_unique` style and only-immutable-shared-data based threading are composible strategies.  This means if small pieces are correct, and you put them together, the resulting program is correct (with regards to resource lifetime and concurrency).  That permits local mastery of small-scale threading or resource management to apply to larfe-scale programs in the domain that these strategies work.

Comment: wow, thanks for the feedback, i will work on it and will post my results an my future questions.
Reading the next lines may make you think that i totaly missed the point, you are warned :)
I know that the Class had some problems, and i knew that using a not syncronized is_running_ could cause a lot damage. 
But in my expections (as a C++ Beginner) i though that the sleep of 500 ms befor the stop and the sleep of 2 seconds after the stop should be enough as a bodge to make sure that the last access to the functions is before the main thread goes out of scope.
However, time to fix the code:)

Comment: @mac.1 If you read data without synchronization, it is undefined behavior.  In this case, in release, the reading thread cached the result of the read.  It knew that there was no synchronization with the read, so it could read it once, and **never look at it again**, because there was no defined way for it to be modified.  It couldn't happen in this thread, and with no synchronization, it is allowed to ignore the possibility of it happening in other threads.  UB means that the compiler is free to assume it doesn't happen, and optimize as if it doesn't happen.

Comment: @Yakk mysterious, i followed your tipps one by one, and suddenly the code is working ;)
Thank your very much!
It makes sense that due to the UB some optimization kicks in which made it so hard for me to understand the problem.
I will post my new code as an answer, and unless you say it's super bad i can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

After following the guide from @Yakk i decided to restructure my programm:

1. `bool is_running_` will change to `td::atomic<bool> is_running_`
2. `stop()` will not only trigger the stopping, but will activly wait for the thread to stop via a `thread_->join()`
3. all calls of `new` are replaced with `std::make_unique<std::thread>( &LoopThread::executeLoop, this )`
4. I have no experience with copy or move constructors. So i decided to forbid them. This should prevent me from accidently using this. If i sometime in the future will need those i have to take a deepter look on thoose
5. `thread_->detach()` was replaced by `thread_->join()` (see 2.)

This is the end of the list.

```
class LoopThread {
public:
    LoopThread(std::function<void(LoopThread*, uint32_t)> function) : function_{ function }, is_running_{ false }, counter_{ 0 } {};
    LoopThread(LoopThread &&) = delete;
    LoopThread(const LoopThread &) = delete;
    LoopThread& operator=(const LoopThread&) = delete;
    LoopThread& operator=(LoopThread&&) = delete;
    ~LoopThread();
    void start();
    void stop();
    bool isRunning() const { return is_running_; };
private:
    std::function<void(LoopThread*, uint32_t)> function_;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> thread_;
    std::atomic<bool> is_running_;
    uint32_t counter_;
    void executeLoop();
};

    LoopThread::~LoopThread() {
    if (isRunning()) {
        stop();
    }
}

void LoopThread::start() {
    if (is_running_) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Thread is already running");
    }
    if (thread_ != nullptr) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Thread is not stopped yet");
    }
    is_running_ = true;
    thread_ = std::make_unique<std::thread>( &LoopThread::executeLoop, this );
}

void LoopThread::stop() {
    if (!is_running_) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Thread is already stopped");
    }
    is_running_ = false;
    thread_->join();
    thread_ = nullptr;
}

void LoopThread::executeLoop() {
    while (is_running_) {
        function_(this, counter_);
        ++counter_;
    }
}

TEST(pfThread, TestLoop)
{
    pft::LoopThread loop{ std::bind(&testFunction, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2) };
    loop.start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
    loop.stop();
}
```